# protoc not generating service stub files

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc

I have just started playing with google proto. When I try to compile proto file present in proto-java example, it does not generate any grpc file.

proto file,
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/src/main/proto/hello_world.proto

terminal output,

> rsonkhla@raman-OptiPlex-9020:~/sandbox/grpc-java/examples$ protoc
>   --version libprotoc 3.0.0 rsonkhla@raman-OptiPlex-9020:~/sandbox/grpc-java/examples$ protoc
>   --java_out=test/ -I../../grpc-java/examples ../../grpc-java/examples/src/main/proto/hello_world.proto 
>   rsonkhla@raman-OptiPlex-9020:~/sandbox/grpc-java/examples$ ls -R test/
>   test/: io
>
> test/io: grpc
>
> test/io/grpc: examples
>
> test/io/grpc/examples: helloworld
>
> test/io/grpc/examples/helloworld: HelloRequest.java
>   HelloResponse.java           HelloWorldProto.java
>   HelloRequestOrBuilder.java  HelloResponseOrBuilder.java

Has anybody else faced this issue?

Comment: Please ignore. I did not pass protoc-gen-grpc-java plugin path while compiling...

Comment: rsonkhla@raman-OptiPlex-9020:~/sandbox/grpc-java/examples$ protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-java_rpc=../compiler/build/binaries/java_pluginExecutable/protoc-gen-grpc-java --java_rpc_out=test/ --java_out=test/ -I. src/main/proto/hello_world.proto                                                                                      

test/io/grpc/examples/helloworld:
GreeterGrpc.java  HelloRequest.java  HelloRequestOrBuilder.java  HelloResponse.java  HelloResponseOrBuilder.java  HelloWorldProto.java

Comment: I use protobuf-maven-plugin, It also can't generate service stub files.

Comment: 404 on that github link

Answer (score 39):

The command line you are showing does not enable the grpc plugin. You need to specify an _out argument for the grpc plugin, which enables the plugin and specifies where it should output files. Since the plugin is likely not in your `PATH`, you also need to tell protoc how to find the plugin with `--plugin`.

So you need to add two arguments:

```
--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-java=path/to/protoc-gen-grpc-java --grpc-java_out=path/to/output/dir
```

For more info, see the gRPC [compiler documentation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/compiler).

Comment: Hi Eric, i'm trying to make this work, i've downloaded protoc-gen-grpc-java.jar from maven, but no matter how i feed it to that argument it will still tell me that "file not found or is not executable", maybe i shall have some other artifact instead of jar file?

Comment: is your "path/to/protoc-gen-grpc-java" pointing to a jar file or something else?

Comment: path/to/protoc-gen-grpc-java is a binary (e.g., a native ELF binary for Linux).  It is not a JAR. You can find pre-built versions at http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22io.grpc%22%20a%3A%22protoc-gen-grpc-java%22 (e.g., linux-x86_32.exe, which could be used like `--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-java=path/to/linux-x86_32.exe`)

Comment: Thanks i've already compiled it from github project, although it was generating not valid code (grpc-all.jar was missing some code which was used in generated one) so i just created a gradle mini project which only takes care of protobuf part... i hope we will have official support for sbt in future...

Comment: @EricAnderson Thans, this is what I was looking for. However, ELF binary with .exe suffix, it sounds really weird ;) I didn't believe that it's really what need when I found it for the first time...

Answer (score 34):

You can add these [option](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#options) to your .proto (base on your language) to generate abstract services:

```
option cc_generic_services = true;
option java_generic_services = true;
option py_generic_services = true;
```

You can also add `--plugin=EXECUTABLE` option in your `protoc` cmd to use custom `code generator plugin` to generate code more specific to each system, rather than rely on the "abstract" services. Just like Eric's suggestion.