# Not getting method name or class name in native java from proto

Tags: grpc, grpc-java, protoc

I have created a proto file

```
  syntax = "proto3";

package example;

message HelloRequest {
    string name = 1;
}

message HelloResponse {
    string greeting = 1;
}

// 4. service, unary request/response
service GreetingService {
    rpc GetGreetingMethod(HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse);
}
```

When I generate the code for golang I can see GetGreetingMethod method in test.pb.go (protoc --go_out=plugins=grpc:. test.proto)

But when I generate the java code ( protoc dir/test.proto --java_out=proto)  I get file where I cant find my rpc function.
Same can be checked [here](http://protobuf-compiler.herokuapp.com/). Any suggestion ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gRPC-java - Compilation of a .proto file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415938/grpc-java-compilation-of-a-proto-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415938/grpc-java-compilation-of-a-proto-file

Comment: Thanks @EricAnderson  and dominik