# protoc command not generating all base classes (java)

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java, protobuf-java

I have been trying to generate the basic gRPC client and server interfaces from a `.proto` service definition [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/src/main/proto/route_guide.proto) from the grpc official repo. 
The relevant service defined in that file (from the link above) is below:

```
service RouteGuide {
    rpc GetFeature(Point) returns (Feature) {}
    rpc ListFeatures(Rectangle) returns (stream Feature) {}
    rpc RecordRoute(stream Point) returns (RouteSummary) {}
    rpc RouteChat(stream RouteNote) returns (stream RouteNote) {}
}
```

The command I run is `protoc --java_out=${OUTPUT_DIR} path/to/proto/file`

According to the grpc site (specifically [here](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/java.html)), a `RouteGuideGrpc.java` which contains a base class `RouteGuideGrpc.RouteGuideImplBase`, with all the methods defined in the RouteGuide service is **supposed** to have been generated from the `protoc` command above, but that file does not get generated for me.

Has anyone faced similar issues? Is the official documentation simply incorrect? And would anyone have any suggestion as to what I can do to generate that missing class?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This may help someone else in the future so I'll answer my own question.

I believe the java documentation for gRPC code generation is not fully up to date and the information is scattered amongst different official repositories.

So turns out that in order to generate all the gRPC java service base classes as expected, you need to specify an additional flag to the `protoc` cli like so `grpc-java_out=${OUTPUT_DIR}`. But in order for that additional flag to work, you need to have a few extra things:

1. The binary for the  protoc plugin for gRPC Java `protoc-gen-grpc-java`: you can get the relevant one for your system from maven central [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/io/grpc/protoc-gen-grpc-java/1.17.1/) (the link is for v1.17.1). If there isn't a prebuilt binary available for your system, you can compile one yourself from the github repo instructions [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/COMPILING.md).
2. Make sure the binary location is added to your PATH environment variable and the binary is renamed to "`protoc-gen-grpc-java`" exactly (that is the name the `protoc` cli expects to have in the path).
3. Finally, you are ready to run the correct command `protoc --java_out=${OUTPUT_DIR} --grpc-java_out=${OUTPUT_DIR} path/to/proto/file` and now the service base classes like `RouteGuideGrpc.RouteGuideImplBase` should be generated when it previously was not.

I hope this explanation helps someone else out in the future.

Comment: Instead of renaming to `proto-gen-grpc-java` you can also use the `--plugin` flag. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31031346/4690866

Comment: Thanks this helped me. I want to add a point. Not sure whether this is addressed in the doc.
`java_out` - created classes for all messages and respective builders
`grpc-java_out` - created the base and stub classes for the services

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for this investigation. Indeed, the doc is incomplete, and people use Maven to compile everything without understanding of how it really works. Yp

Comment: This does not have any answer