# gRPC Java Codegen Plugin for Protobuf Compiler

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protoc

Updating question as I've progressed from the original problem.

**Step 1**. I've compiled and Installed Protobuf Compiler for mac using this [link](https://medium.com/@erika_dike/installing-the-protobuf-compiler-on-a-mac-a0d397af46b8).

**Step 2**. Currently stuck at gRPC Java Codegen Plugin for Protobuf Compiler [link](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/compiler):

Successful    `../gradlew java_pluginExecutable`

Error `../gradlew test` (screenshot 1)

> *** Building codegen requires Protobuf version 3.9.0

---

`which protoc` outputs `/usr/local/bin/protoc`

`protoc --version` outputs `libprotoc 3.9.0`

**P.S.** Please also mention in your solution what to do next once I'm able to compile java generator, I plan to use the plugin from command line initially.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31031346/7736617

Comment: I tried the example from the linked question, and got this error, `--grpc-java_out: protoc-gen-grpc-java: Plugin failed with status code 1.` what's next for me? Where do I find and install this plugin?

Comment: The answer also provides a link to the documentation, which provides an example. https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/compiler

Comment: ok, followed the steps. I've compiled for my system (mac), and installed the codegen to maven repository using `../gradlew publishToMavenLocal`, the plugin fail error persists, what's next please?

Comment: i've added this to the command with path to .m2  `--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-java=~/.m2/repository/protoc-gen-grpc-java --grpc-java_out=path/to/output/dir` I don't see however, the file under .m2, so where do I find `protoc-gen-grpc-java` file?

Comment: It should be in `io/grpc/protoc-gen-grpc-java/` but you should be able to download a compiled one, https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/grpc/protoc-gen-grpc-java/1.22.1/

Comment: made progress but stuck at this `Building codegen requires Protobuf version 3.9.0`, however, `protoc --version` returns `libprotoc 3.9.0`

Comment: What's exactly you problem ? Update your question with the new elements

Comment: question updated, please have a look

Comment: Have you try with a compiled one ? I can't reproduce, it's working for me

Comment: took another route, from inside `protobuf-3.9.0/java` i ran `mvn install`, error screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/APw6o.png

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel I'm still stuck at getting this java gen grpc to compile, instead can you plese provide me the jar file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your use case, maybe you do not have build the codegen by yourself.
As in the link https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/COMPILING.md

> Since many Java developers don't have C compilers installed and don't need to run or modify the codegen, the build can skip it. To skip, create the file /gradle.properties and add skipCodegen=true.

If you really need to, there are steps you can follow in that link too.

Comment: Is there any reason to not use pre-compiled binary? Could you please tell us what you are trying to do and what have you done?

Comment: where can i get the pre-compiled library and how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/compiler

This link now contains detailed generation command and where the prebuilt protoc-gen-grpc plugin can be downloaded.

Where and how to download the pre-built protoc-gen-rpc plugin:

> 1. Navigate to [https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.grpc/protoc-gen-grpc->](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.grpc/protoc-gen-grpc-%3E) 2. java
> 2. Click into a version
> 3. Click "Files"
> 4. Select and download the one that is compatible with your system

Generate code with command line tool `protoc`

> ```
> $ protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-java=/path/to/your/downloaded/protoc-gen-grpc-java \
>   --grpc-java_out="$OUTPUT_FILE" --proto_path="$DIR_OF_PROTO_FILE" "$PROTO_FILE"
> ```