# Problem when auto generating gRPC stub files using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, protocol-buffers, grpc-java, protoc

I've been asked to implement some gRPC classes for a college course, and have run into some problems when generating the java classes from one source proto file.

Some background first: it's a fairly basic service, with a simple method that receives an id and returns a phone and an email. This is the proto file (BuscarData means FetchData, sorry for the leftover non translation!):

```
syntax = 'proto3';
option java_multiple_files=true;
option java_generic_services= true;
package  uy.edu.um.sd20;

message DataRequest {
  int32 id = 1;
}

message DataResponse {
  string phone = 1;
  string email = 2;
}

service DataRepo {
  rpc BuscarData (DataRequest) returns (DataResponse);
}
```

The idea I had was to generate the classes with gradle plugins. My build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "com.google.protobuf" version '0.8.8'
}
apply plugin: 'java'

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'com.google.protobuf', name: 'protobuf-java', version: '3.11.4'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:1.29.0'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.29.0'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.29.0'

}

sourceSets {
    main {
        proto {
            srcDir 'src/main/proto'
        }
        java {
            srcDirs 'src/main/java', 'generated-sources/main/java'
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.11.0'
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.29.0'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks.generatedFilesBaseDir = 'generated-sources'

    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            // Here you can configure the task
        }
        ofSourceSet('main')

    }
}
```

From what I understood, everything's there: the grpc and protoc dependencies, and the plugin which enables protoc to compile grpc (protoc-gen-grpc), and where to deposit the generated files.
However,  there are two problems:

1. the generated-sources are not marked as source or anything like that, meaning they cannot be imported from other classes
2. if I'm not mistaken, the generated-sources should generate a skeleton of DataRepoImpl so that I can add the code needed for BuscarData. However, it didn't. Or maybe I should create it, extending from DataRepo.java, but I couldn't test it, due to problem n°1.

I've added a screenshot of the project file structure:
 [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bERo.png)

As you can see, quite a lot (if not *all*) of the gradle settings are copy-pasted and scavenged from many different web-sites. I hope I was careful enough not to repeat any imports. There are similar questions, and I tried the solutions there, but no luck there. One example, with which I knew I had to include the gen grpc plugin: [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029675/protoc-not-generating-service-stub-files)

Any tip regarding anything else is welcome! I'm new to stackoverflow question-asking, so I may have made mistakes regarding the question specificity or aim of the question.

Thanks!

Franri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1), the plugin should put the generated files are the input for java compile tasks even if you do not explicitly add `'generated-sources/main/java'` in the `sourceSets` configuration. Version 0.8.8 has been a while, you can try with newer versions. There might have been some minor fixes for things you may hit.

For 2), you did not add `grpc` plugin to each `generateProto` task. It should be

```
generateProtoTasks {
    all().each { task ->
        task.plugins { grpc{} }
    }
    ofSourceSet('main')

}
```